# How to combine two query and output result is horizontal

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have two table which record Monthly-Allowance and OT-Allowance which both table have Department column and Track column
I need report that have all department but separate with Track Column 'DL','IDL'

I can do it only one Track but i can't combine with Track column in one query
This is my code

```
;WITH sums AS 
(
   SELECT
      sum(Monthly.Pay) as Total_Monthly,OT.MealAllowance_OT,Monthly.Dept_Id,Monthly.Dept_Name

   FROM
     [dbo].[SPCM_TX_MonthlyAllowance] as Monthly
     left join (  select Period,sum(MealAllowance_OT) MealAllowance_OT,Dept_Id
   from [dbo].[SPCM_Cal_OTLog]
   where Track = 'IDL'
   group by Period,Dept_Id) OT
   on Monthly.Dept_Id = OT.Dept_Id  
   where Monthly.Track = 'IDL'
   GROUP BY
      Monthly.Dept_Id, Monthly.Dept_Name,MealAllowance_OT,Monthly.Track
)
SELECT   
   Dept_Id,Dept_Name,Total_Monthly,MealAllowance_OT,Total_Monthly+MealAllowance_OT AS 'GrandTotal' 
FROM 
   sums  
   order by GrandTotal desc
```

Monthly_Table

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
EMP_ID  |  Track  |  Period      |  Pay  |  Dept_Id  |  Dept_Name  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1           DL       2019-10-10     400       1A           A        
2           IDL      2019-10-10     400       1A           A
3           DL       2019-10-10     400       1B           B
4           IDL      2019-10-10     400       1B           B
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

OT_Table

---

```
EMP_ID  |  Track  |  Period     |  OTHrs| Meallowance_OT  | Dept_Id | Dept_Name | Day_Type
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           DL       2019-10-10     5         18             1A           A         Working_day
2           IDL      2019-10-10     5         18             1A           A         Weekend
3           DL       2019-10-10     10        18             1B           B         PublicHoliday
4           IDL      2019-10-10     12         0             1B           B         Working_day
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Result
[image]

Comment: You're after a `JOIN`.

Comment: Join my command right ?